# How to read string with space within loops in java?

Tags: java, string, loops, whitespace

We all know that using method input.nextLine() will allow spaces for the string while running the program, but.. When I use this method inside a loop the run skips the statement. Can anyone please explain why?

I'm trying it with menu:

Code:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
    choice = input.nextInt();

    switch (choice) {

    case 4:
        System.out.println("Please give the full information of the project ");
        System.out.print("Project code: "); int code = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Project Title: "); String title = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Project Bonus in Percent: "); double bip = input.nextDouble();
        Project proj4 = new Project(code4,title4,bip4);
        System.out.print("Employee ID you're adding project to: "); String id4=input.next();
        ers.addProjectToEmployee(id4,proj4);
        break;

    /* more cases  */
    }
} while (choice !=13);
```

Check statement 3 in case 4.

Here's what happened while running the program:

```
Enter your choice: 4
Please give the full information about the project 
Project code: 66677
Project Title: Project Bonus in Percent:
```

Comment: Orthogonal to your question, but consider placing all of the functionality in your `case`s in different methods.  It would make debugging them easier, as you don't have a whole mess of code staring you in the face.

Comment: @Makoto You mean you want me to share the whole code? :P

Comment: No.  How'd you come to that thought?  :S

Comment: @Makoto I'm not sure.. x_x Forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input.nextInt()` does not read the end-of-line, so that' why the effect that `.nextLine()` is being escaped, while actually that `.nextLine()` is reading the end-of-line left unread in the input-stream by the `.nextInt()`. You need an extra `.nextLine()` after `.nextInt()`.

---

**Update:**

Do the following:

```
System.out.print("Project code: "); int code = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // this is what you need to add
System.out.print("Project Title: "); String title = input.nextLine();
```